# Many questions about the same broken reCAPTCHA sample code

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

It seems that, [somewhere on the Internet](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/), there's a badly written PHP code sample<sup>1</sup> purportedly explaining how to implement reCAPTCHA. Users frequently come to Stack Overflow to ask problems about this code, and *most of the answers fail to fix it correctly*. (Specifically, most of them fail to identify that, in PHP, `$response.success==false` is never true.)

There are a *lot* of questions about this code. Some of the ones I was able to easily find by searching for fragments of the sample code include:

- [New Google ReCaptcha not posting/receiving 'g-recaptcha-response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683888/new-google-recaptcha-not-posting-receiving-g-recaptcha-response)
- [New Google ReCaptcha Implementation And checking before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686269/new-google-recaptcha-implementation-and-checking-before-submit)
- [Why is the From email field not getting set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570942/why-is-the-from-email-field-not-getting-set)
- [Google No captcha Recaptcha not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596429/google-no-captcha-recaptcha-not-working)
- [Google Recaptcha Always Return False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618372/google-recaptcha-always-return-false)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632990/google-recaptcha-api-error

What's the best way to handle "sort-of-duplicate" questions like these? Not all of them are asking exactly the same question, but all of their problems are stemming from the same source (namely, that the sample code they're trying to use is totally bogus).

---

1. Yes, I know, that's arguably redundant. ;)

Comment: OMFG, there's even accepted answer about valitating it ON CLIENT: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30532605/936986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for a [self-answered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). In the answer,

- Critically examine the pitfalls you've identified.
- Cite the Q&A in the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/captcha/info) of the  [captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captcha) tag.
- Use the Q&A to close duplicates or cite it in a comment on "sort-of-duplicate" questions.
- Promote the Q&A among [those wielding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/captcha/topusers) [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/163188).